# Combined Binomial Distribution Problem.

Tags: probability-distributions, binomial-distribution

I have the following problem:
70% of women respond positively to a test, while only 40% of men do so. If 10 participants are selected (5 women and 5 men), what is the probability that only 1 man responds negatively?

Now what I have done is to have two distributions, one for women and one for men. Then I calculated P(Y=5) for women with p=0.7 and P(Y=4) for men with p=0.4, and since the events are mutually exclusive I´ve added the two, having a result of ~24%. Can this be correct...?

Comment: This method isn't quite right, but even if it were, it shouldn't give 24%. What are you doing to calculate $P_W(Y=5)$ and $P_M(Y=4)$?

Comment: P(Y=5) = 5C5 * 0.7^5 * 0.3^0 and P(Y=4) = 5C4 * 0.4^4 * 0.6^1

Comment: Oh yeah, that's right. I'll type up an answer now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The events of $5$ women out of $5$ respond positively and $4$ men out of $5$ respond positively are not mutually exclusive.  In fact it is perhaps reasonable to assume that they are independent, and so you can multiply the probabilities.

Comment: It's just one experiment, are they not mutually exclusive...?

Comment: For a positive outcome, you require *both* that exactly five women respond positively *and* that exactly four men respond positively. I think you might be mixing up "mutually exclusive" and "independent" (the latter of which you can probably assume, as paw points out).

Comment: In that case, when you consider two experiments, selecting 5 women who respond positively and selecting 4 men who do so also, then the probability is ~1.2907%. And in that case they might be independent events.

Comment: That's right. See my answer if you are still unclear.

Answer (score 0):

You have the right idea, but did some wrong calculations.

The probability of 4 men responding positively and one man responding negatively is $_5C_4(0.4)^4(0.6)^1$.

The probability of 5 women responding positively is $_5C_5(0.7)^5(0.3)^0$.

The product of these two calculations is what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Almost!

You've correctly figured out how to calculate the probability of picking five women and four men answering positively: $$P_W(X=5)= {5 \choose 5} (0.7)^5 (0.3)^0 \approx .168$$ $$P_M(X=4)= {5 \choose 4} (0.4)^4 (0.6)^1 \approx .077$$

Your mistake was in adding the two. You require that *both* of these events occur. Since they are independent, you may simply multiply the probabilities of the events occurring individually to obtain this: $$.168 \times .077 \approx .013$$

---

To more clearly see why you cannot add the two, recalculate your answer in the case where women answer positively $100\%$ of the time. You'll get a likelihood of more than $100\%$!